# Swift can't find text file from XCode bundle

Tags: swift, xcode

Trying to learn Swift: seemingly a very simple problem, solution copied from accepted Stack Overflow answers, but the text.txt and real.txt files are never found. The path constant is always set to nil.

I also tried code with filename of just "text" and ofType: "txt", and with the .url() instead of .path()

I looked into the project build directory, the .txt files are never copied there.

What simple knowledge am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Is this created from the command line tool template? If so, you can't get bundle resources because there is no bundle. You know you don't have to use `Bundle.main.path`, right? Just hardcode the path to your file relative to the current directory.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55932345/5133585

Comment: Yes, it was indeed created from the command line template, that explains the problem I guess.